# Manipulate database of WordPress site with my own scripts

Tags: php, database, scripts

I love WordPress as it provides plenty of great themes, good SEO and overall content management.

But I'm not always happy with WordPress's original "Add post" and "Edit post" features as it required manual work to provide the content for the site.

However all the data of WordPress site stored in the database which can be easily manipulated by 'handwritten' script (PHP for example). It'd look promising but I'd be afraid of crashing WordPress-specific data structure and invoke mistakes in the site work or even make it inaccessible. Moreover WordPress has its own caching and probably many other things I should take care about before I get started.

So my questions are:

1) Is it even possible and (more important) reasonable to manipulate the WordPress database by handwritten script?

2) If the answer for the 1st question is 'Yes' - is there any tools (for PHP in the first place) which can make this process more save and pleasant?

3) Is there any reading for the task I'd like to accomplish? I tried to Google a little bit but I didn't find any even close to this (I tried a queries like 'wordpress database manipulation', 'wordpress post by php script' and so on).

Comment: If you want to manipulate the database, I'd suggest looking at the WPDB class which manages all of WordPress' database activity: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @john, after brief WPDB's documentation reading I'm comming to the conclusion that it's not a thing I'm looking for: it seams like to be just a DB gateway like PHP's PDO. So I'm afraid that cache issue, data consistensy and probably many other issues will be up to me. Right? Is there any higher level classes?

Comment: Codex is the best place to look. Eg Insert a post: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post. Most of the important functions that WordPress uses are in the function reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/